# TWAIN chrome usb api

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, twain, scanning

As we know google chrome provide USB API.
http://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb.html

But examples only 2.

Can you help to understand. How use twain from usb api? Is this possible or very hard?
Or my question is incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

USB and TWAIN are two different protocals.

Are you looking at interracting with TWAIN devices from Google Chrome? If so, you will need a TWAIN plugin for Chrome. There are 3rd-party TWAIN browser plugins available, like Dynamsoft's [Dynamic Web TWAIN](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/WebTWAIN_Overview.aspx). You can check it out. (Disclaimer: I work for the company)

Comment: Can you do that (scan documents) for some scanner with modern USB-WEB API (which, at the moment of writing, is implemented only in Chrome) ?  (without ANY plug-ins)

Comment: We now support TWAIN API, plus ICA on macOS and SANE on Linux. An HTML5/JavaScript library is provided to support scan in modern browsers to replace the old ActiveX and plug-in. 
Will look into the new USB-WEB API.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [Wikipedia page for TWAIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWAIN):

> TWAIN is not a hardware-level protocol; it requires a driver called Data Source for each device.

Which means that you cannot hope to implement your own (device-independent) TWAIN on top of raw USB, as it is not a protocol carried by USB.

As mentioned in another answer, this can be solved with plugins that interface with OS-level TWAIN API.

---

**Edit:** Apparently, there is an API in the works: [`chrome.documentScan`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/documentScan)

It is not stable at the moment and only available for Dev builds.